# glmmadmb help: multiple errors when running models

Tags: r, mixed-models, poisson

I'm trying to run a mixed effects model that includes three fixed effects with interaction and a random intercept and slope. The model I'm trying to specify in glmmadmb is:

```
> fit_zipoiss_ambig<-glmmadmb(AmbigCount~Posn.c*mood.c*Valence.c + offset(InputAmbig) + (1+Valence.c|mood.c/Chain), data = Data, zeroInflation = TRUE, family="poisson")
```

First I received this error message:

```
Error in Droplevels(eval(parse(text = x), data)) : 
  all grouping variables in random effects must be factors
```

So I used (as an example) `fPosn.c=as.factor(Data$Posn.c)`to convert all my predictors to factors. Then I ran this model:

```
> fit_zipoiss_ambig<-glmmadmb(AmbigCount~fPosn.c*fmood.c*fValence.c + offset(InputAmbig) + (1+fValence.c|fmood.c/Chain), data = Data, zeroInflation = TRUE, family="poisson")
```

Then I got this error:

```
Error in glmmadmb(AmbigCount ~ fPosn.c * fmood.c * fValence.c + offset(InputAmbig) +  : 
  The function maximizer failed (couldn't find STD file) Troubleshooting steps include (1) run with 'save.dir' set and inspect output files; (2) change run parameters: see '?admbControl'
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library/glmmADMB/bin/windows64/glmmadmb.exe" -maxfn 500 -maxph 5 -noinit -shess' had status 1
```

I tried to follow the troubleshooting advice so included `, admb.opts=admbControl(shess=FALSE,noinit=FALSE))` at the end of my model. Now I am receiving this error:

```
Error in glmmadmb(AmbigCount ~ fPosn.c * fmood.c * fValence.c + offset(InputAmbig) +  : 
  rank of X = 106 < ncol(X) = 107
```

I have no idea what this error means. I'm hoping someone can help me work out how to specify my model in glmmadmb or failing that, some other package that will allow me to test a poisson or negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to run it myself, what jumps out at me is:

1. As far as your first error message, it is saying that the variables in your nested random-effects formula need to be factors.
2. Then, in your code: fPosn.c=as.factor(Data$Posn.c)
   you are not creating "fPosn.c" within your data frame. To do that you need to run:
   Data$fPosn.c = as.factor(Data$Posn.c)